# Pase bbcode with exceptions

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

```
$pattern = "/\[url\=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/i";
```

My pattern above rewrites bbcode to html but I want to exclude links from my own domain. Is it possible to modify the regex so it will work for all external links but not for links with my own domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to do something like that you normally use the [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) function.

It allows you to specify a callback function that can check further conditions prior offering the replacement string which allows to "replace" with the same so no replacement is done.

```
$pattern = "/\[url\=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/i";
$callback = function($matches)
{
    $url = $matches[1];
    if (is_own_domain_url($url)) {
        return $matches[0]; # no changes
    } else {
        $title = $matches[2];
        return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>'
                , htmlspecialchars($url)
                , htmlspecialchars($title)
        );
    }
}

$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern $callback, $bbcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your domain is `example.com`, this pattern does the job:

```
/\[url\=((?:(?!example\.com).)*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/i
```

Comment: This does not always work, like for `[url=%65xample.com]my own domain, linked[/url]` as an URL allows multiple ways to express the same character - which often is not compatbile with simple regexes.